# resizing li elements with CSS

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I have a list of results that I want to show the user, I looks like this:

Wins: 1 | 15 | 33 |

Lose: 7 | 65 | 100 |

Now the numbers are all in an unordered list and the design almost works fine. The problem is it may be likely that one of these numbers will go to three digits as show above (I want them to align with each other top and bottom).

So I try to resize the `li` element by using

```
#my_list li
{
    width: 100px; /*Exmaple width*/
}
```

This seems to do nothing so i looked around and found a lot of tutorials for nav bars. These show the resize in the `<a>` tag but i don't have any links for these numbers.

So my question is, is there a way of resizing the width of the li tag itself? If not is there an HTML5 tag that is semantically suitable to wrap these numbers in and then resize that element like you would the a tag for links?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Used to** `display:inline-block` **or** `float:left`

**Try this** css

```
#my_list li
{
    min-width: 100px; /*Exmaple width*/

}
```

**or** don't define `width`

```
#my_list li
{
padding:0 10px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
 }
```

Comment: That is perfect sir! Adding display:inline-block allows me to resize the li elements. Thank you very much, i spent way to much time on that.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a classic case which requires a `TABLE`, *NOT* `UL`. By using a table you ensure perfect alignment no matter how many digits there are, as the cells automatically expand to contain the content.

EDIT:As for inconsistent no. of `TD`'s in each `TR`, Look at this simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucCWR/) where you can see how flexible tables are even when the no. of TD's for each row is different. Moreover,You can easily fix such inconsistencies with the `COLSPAN` HTML attribute. That is, you find out which row has most `TD`'s and this will be your total column number. Then you just calculate the ((TOTAL - ACTUAL) +1), and pass this value as the last TD's `COLSPAN`.

Comment: The problem i've found with using a table is that the values i have on this page come from a database so its the amount of values is unknown and tables seem to not be so flexible for example is one row has more values that the other.

Comment: Well that does make sense, i used to use tables for situations like this before but i found i would get so many bugs and have to hack away at it till it was right. Plus with using lists and containers i have a lot more control over what i want them to do and where they should be positioned and feel that the control over these elements is a lot easier to work with...... Most of the time! Thanks for the post I'm going to look into using tables again i think.

Answer (score 1):

U should put it into `display:inline-block` and set a `width` for it,

here is a live example: [DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/uwN7t/)